# Positive and negative expressions with <Talk about + friend>

Tags: phrase-usage

I was wondering how you could use ***talk about*** with ***friend*** to show

- disappointment
- contentment

in a friend.

For example, to be critical you could say: Some friend he is!

And to be flattering you maybe ... not sure... might say: Quite a friend he is

I would like to see an example for each case using ***talk about friend***. I noticed that *talk about* could be used with adjectives as well as nouns.

> **2 informal** - used to emphasize the size, amount, or extent of something
>
> - *Talk about rain! I've never seen it rain like this in my entire life!*
> - *Talk about having a bad day. I had the worst day ever!*
> - *Talk about short. She's only four feet tall!*

Merriam Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary

**Edit:**

- A positive articulation:*Talk about best friends! Dylan has never failed me. He's always been there*
- A negative articulation:*Talk about friends! Jerry told Dad I was smoking again; such a fink.*

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Are you trying to talk about a particular friend? Say someone is a good friend or bad friend? Or what?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want

Comment: I cannot find any confirmation of this in any of the online dictionaries, but my impression is that **talk about** is generally used when we want to introduce a negative description of something. "Talk about stupid... you can see his lips moving when he is reading". "Talk about slow... he offered me a cup of tea but I was dying of thirst by the time he had made it."

Answer (score 2):

The phrase

> talk about *something*

is used to emphasize how extreme *something* is, either positive or negative. It can be used to introduce a new subject or comment on an existing topic, especially in conversation.

> Talk about strong coffee, you could stand a spoon in it.

[image: here]

> Talk about fast, he can out run a cheetah.

[image: here]

> Talk about high heels, she was basically standing on her toes!

[image: here]

Comment: Thanks Peter. How about, "Talk about best friends! Dylan has never failed me. He's always been there"

Comment: and how about this negative one, "Talk about friends! Jerry told Dad I was smoking again; such a fink."

Comment: @lerner Both of those are correct and understandable.